# Сегментация памяти, assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Начал изучать низкоуровневое программирование, не могу понять как работает сегментация памяти в реальном режиме, объясните понятным языком
Заранее спасибо

Comment: `Адрес = Адрес_Сегмента * 16 + Смещение` Этот момент понятен?

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно? Сейчас вопрос слишком общий, ответом будет по сути копипаста из учебника.